# Split one column into multiple columns with delimiter starting from the end of the string - Python Data science

Tags: python, data-science

Please How do I split one column into multiple columns with delimiter
starting from the end of the string? e.g

> 2014_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents
> 2015_Copa_AmÃ©rica_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents
> 2016_Summer_Olympics_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents
> 2018_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents
> 2014_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_mobile-web_all-agents
> A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire_en.wikipedia.org_desktop_all-agents

```
enter code here
```

Comment: What does your desired output look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the delimiter you want to split on is `_`. In that case,

```py
long_string = """2014_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents
2015_Copa_AmÃ©rica_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents
2016_Summer_Olympics_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents
2018_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents
2014_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_mobile-web_all-agents
A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire_en.wikipedia.org_desktop_all-agents"""
lines = long_string.split("\n")
columns = [line.split("_") for line in lines]
print(columns)
```

gives you

```
[['2014', 'FIFA', 'World', 'Cup', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'], 
['2015', 'Copa', 'AmÃ©rica', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'],
['2016', 'Summer', 'Olympics', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'],
['2018', 'FIFA', 'World', 'Cup', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'], 
['2014', 'FIFA', 'World', 'Cup', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'mobile-web', 'all-agents'], 
['A', 'Song', 'of', 'Ice', 'and', 'Fire', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'desktop', 'all-agents']]
```

Comment: I intend to make the string read from Right to left in order to split the line into different groups. I still can't run my analysis properly with the 'long_string.split @Elijah cox

Comment: Please specify your desired output and why it's different from mine. @tolubrymoh

Comment: I wanted a situation where we could find the no of languages within the columns that starts with en.wikipedia. but I think sql sorted it better. thanks @elijahcox